# Spring RefreshScope with SpEL deferred Evaluation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, refresh, spring-boot-actuator

I'm having trouble knowing how this is possible or a potential work around. I am looking at configuring variables that are in the form of "foo,bar,baz" into a List as separate elements. Currently the code looks like

```java
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@Getter
public class fakeConfiguration {
    @Value("#{PropertySplitter.toSet('${properties:}')}")
    private final Set<String> field = new HashSet<>();
}   

@Component("PropertySplitter")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class PropertySplitter {
    public Set<String> toSet(String property) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        if(!property.trim().isEmpty()){
            Collections.addAll(set, property.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        }

        return set;
    }
}
```

This properly evaluates the String list into a Set however the refreshScope never gets triggered properly. If I use

```
    @Value("${properties:}")
    private final String fieldAsString;
```

I can see the field properly refresh, but I'd like to actively convert the value to a list as it is changed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. In newer version of spring-boot below works for `application.properties` and `Application.yml`

```
    @Value("#{${props.list}}")
    private List<String> fieldList;
```

2. If you use `Application.yml` you can arrange the objects

```
    props:
      list:
        - val1
        - val2
```

and then use in code

```
    @Value("${props.list}")
    private List<String> ymlList
```

Last, You can try the below as well

```
    @Value("#{'${props.list}'.split(',')}") 
    private List<String> myList;
```